# 12.10 Blank Boot Screen after Installing Over Windows 7

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

So I am a first time Linux user, and wanted to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop that was previously running Windows 7.

I made a live USB drive to try it out, and then used it to go through the installation. (I wiped my old W7 install and replaced it with U12.10.)

Everything completed fine, but now after my BIOS screen there's a blinking cursor for about 4 seconds and then nothing. Just a blank screen indefinitely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/44179

Comment: @yorkcommatyler Review the tread linked by iSeth and if you still have problems edit your answer adding more information (hardware, methods that you tried without results, etc.). Or [create a new Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have grub. I have had no problem with the cd install. try to reinstall with a live cd instead. ?? you can also do a live boot with you live cd and manually install grub. I have not used the usb method, but you can use that if it lets you try it before installing.

Comment: So how do I install grub from the USB stick?

Comment: So I googled the crap out of the situation and limped my way through reinstalling grub. After that didn't solve it, I just reinstalled 12.10. Should have done that from the beginning I suppose because everything is running great now. Thanks for all your help, and I look forward to seeing more of the Ubuntu community!